# Visualisation with PCM wave data

Tags: c#, .net, audio, xna, pcm

I have an API that gives me PCM wave data:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff966424.aspx

> The byte[] buffer format used as a parameter for the SoundEffect
>   constructor, Microphone.GetData method, and
>   DynamicSoundEffectInstance.SubmitBuffer method is PCM wave data.
>   Additionally, the PCM format is interleaved and in little-endian.
>
> The audio format has the following constraints:
>
> - The audio channels can be mono (1) or stereo (2).
> - The PCM wave file
>     must have 16-bits per sample.
> - The sample rate must be between 8,000 Hz
>     and 48,000 Hz.
> - The interleaving for stereo data is left channel to
>     right channel.

I would like to do a visualisation based on this data.

I want to split the sound pitch levels into 3rds, and get the volume/level of each.

So, if i speak in a low voice, i'll get a high value, then 2 low values, if i speak normally i'd get a low value, a high value and a low value and if i speak in a high voice i get 2 low values, and a high value.

How can i achieve this? I've never tried anything dealing with sound, so i'm at level 1, and don't know where to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A full answer would probably be too complex to give here but you need to take the time-domain, PCM sample data and derive the frequency-domain representation from it so that you can then assess the level of the signal in the different frequency ranges. The technique for doing this is known as the [Fast Fourier Transfer (FFT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform). Implementing this yourself requires a significant amount of knowledge of DSP, so perhaps your best approach would be to source a library that offers an FFT implementation out-of-the-box that you can use.

Comment: Also, when you implement the FFT and group your frequencies together, make sure you use a logarithmic scale to display their values - if you use a linear scale the differences between values will be huge (I actually thought my code wasn't working properly because the graph was all over the place when I did a similar visualization using a linear scale)